# Codeigniter active record multiple columns query returning only 1 column's values?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to pull two columns as an array using a technique that has worked for me in other places so far. But it is only returning the first column's values with empty values for the second column.

Here's my controller

```
function status()
{
  $this -> load -> model('model');
  $data['query'] = $this -> model -> checkWebStatus('database');

  if ($this -> uri -> segment(3) == '')
  {
    $this -> template -> set_content('status_view', $data);
    $this -> template -> build();
  }
}
```

The model looks like this:

```
function checkWebStatus($database)
{
  $this -> external_db = $this -> load -> database($database, TRUE);
  $query = $this -> external_db -> select('name_code, active_franchise');
  $query = $this -> external_db -> order_by('active_franchise DESC, name_code ASC');
  $query = $this -> external_db -> get('database_table');

  return($query -> result());
}
```

And my view looks like this...

```
foreach ($query as $result)
{
  echo $result -> name_code;
  print '&nbsp;';
  echo (isset($result -> active_franchise)) ? $result -> active_franchise : 'var unset';
  print '<br />';
}
```

I end up with an array of name_code(s) and accompanying "var unset" messages. Any advice? As I said this system has worked fine before with different names for the columns, the only difference being this database is explicitly set in the model whereas the area it appears to work on is on the default "db" through Codeigniter.

I appreciate your time reading this, thank you.

---EDIT---

Crap I suck, can't believe I missed the typo. BUT. It did not solve the issue. Now instead of showing "var unset" it simply lists no value at all. It should return either a 1 or 0.

---EDIT 2---

var_dump($result) returns....

```
object(stdClass)#24 (2) { ["name_code"]=> string(6) "GECAOC" ["active_franchise"]=> string(1) "" } GECAOC 
object(stdClass)#25 (2) { ["name_code"]=> string(6) "GEPACT" ["active_franchise"]=> string(1) "" } GEPACT 
object(stdClass)#26 (2) { ["name_code"]=> string(6) "GEWAES" ["active_franchise"]=> string(1) "" } GEWAES
```

Comment: Possible typo on the 4'th line of your view file: `echo (isset($result -> active_frachise))` should be `active_franchise`

Comment: I edited above, see changes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
  echo (isset($result -> active_frachise)) ? $result -> active_franchise : 'var unset';
  print '<br />';
```

Change to

```
  echo (isset($result -> active_franchise)) ? $result -> active_franchise : 'var unset';
  print '<br />';
```

It is never even getting to the point where you can echo active franchise because the isset returns false

Comment: Ugh crap I can't believe I missed that; however, I edited with further info... Still not quite working as intended.

Comment: Can you do a var_dump of $result for me?

Comment: Added above. Thanks again for helping out Chitowns24.

Comment: Okay so check your MySQL tables because it shows me that active_franchise is being grabbed correctly because they are "" strings. So your logic is working well just need to check your values in the database!

Comment: Sorry let me clarify a bit, because you are using ternary operators if your value is true it will return active franchise (blank string) or var unset

Comment: Ugh crap using a SELECT `name_code`, `active_franchise` statement on the Table returns the values as intended. It's not something weird with the boolean nature of the values, right?

Comment: Not that I can tell. All I am seeing is, if the variable is set it will return the active franchise otherwise it will return var unset

Comment: Now I'm thoroughly stumped. I'll hold onto this post in case I find a concrete solution to where I've zigged when I should zag. Thanks for the help Chitowns24

Comment: Are you trying to output if the variable is set? Or the actual value of the variable?

Comment: Well that little tidbit came about as error checking. I just wanted to see what was even there if anything. It uses the value of that row/column to decide if a user's information is "turned on" then displays that.

Comment: That is exactly what it is doing right now. I think you're logic is correct

Comment: In my code that tries to decide whether the user is "on" or "off" (it turns that 1 or 0 value into "ENABLED" or "DISABLED" and displays a button) all of the users (even the ones marked as 1 if you look in the database) show as DISABLED.

Answer (score 0):

Got it dead right @Chitowns24 I edited the table's column from bit as the type to tinyint(1) and set it to not null (compared to a VERY similar set to code used in another area that worked and saw that difference in that field) and now it pulls down the value as intended.

Lucky me the code was good I just didn't arrange the table when it was setup!